# how to append inside cells in a cell array without looping?

Tags: matlab, performance, cell-array

I have an array

```
A={1 6 31 65; 1 38 53 4};
```

I want a cell array in the form

```
C={[1 1] [6 6] [31 31] [65 65];[1 1] [38 38] [53 53] [4 4]};
```

One way of doing this is by looping:

```
for count=1:2
    for i=1:4
        for j=1:2
            C{i,j}(count)=A(i,j);
        end
    end
end
```

**How can I do this without looping and improve time complexity?**

Edit: It is not the case for just count=2, I've application where count goes as high as 85. Looping greatly reduces efficiency. And going for higher dimension matrices is also inefficient.

Comment: You don't. Why do you need a cell array? The cells contain arrays that are all the same size.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use `cellfun` to create each new element

```
C = cellfun(@(x)ones(1,2) * x, A, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

As @excaza has pointed out though, you have data of equal sizes so it is recommended that you use a multi-dimensional array instead. You could (for example), just replicate the data along the third dimension instead

```
C = repmat(A, [1 1 2]);
```

Comment: Note that `cellfun` will likely be slower than the explicit loop in cases where the [character function input](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html#inputarg_func) is not supported.

Comment: @excaza In this case though it may be faster since in the example in the question there is no pre-allocation of each cell array element.